# Save button missing

Tags: nodes, 8

I have created a custom type under Drupal 8 Admin page.
but when create a new custom type content, "Save and Publish" button is missing. while, the button is shown on "Basic page" content.

I have to click on  "Preview" button, then click on "back to content editing",
Drupal 8 then redirect me to Edit page, and a button "Save and keep Publish" been shown.

Comment: I have created a fresh Drupal 8 installation, same problem, custom content type has no "Publish and Save" button, is this a Drupal 8 default setup?

Comment: made a interesting discovery, under core\modules\node\src\Nodeform, inside function protected function actions(), if I hard code $element['submit']['#access'] to ture, "Save and Publish" button returned, it seems problem lies in $node->type->entity->getPreviewMode(), I will  report back.

Comment: Waiting for a report :) Please tag me in a comment when you do (Tagging can be done via the @ character).

Comment: @benos , I have found out, this is because , I have turned on "Preview before submit" option. to turn it off, 
    1> Edit the content type
    2> Click "Submission form settings"
    3> Set "Preview before submitting" to Optional

Comment: Oh btw anru, if you are a JS programmer can you please try to help me here? Any help will be good, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/drupal-8-ckeditor-appears-ltr-in-an-rtl-site-flipped-ckeditor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, post an answer here.

This is because I did turned on "Preview before submit" option.

to turn it off, 1> Edit the content type 
2> Click "Submission form settings" 
3> Set "Preview before submitting" to Optional.

But I just find a problem/bug , when you turn on  "Preview before submit".
I am unable to update/modify my content, it always redirect me to "Preview" page.

here is how to reproduce it.

```
1> turn on "Preview before Submitting" option
2> create a content, at first, you can save the content.
3> then try to modify / edit that content again,you will find out 
    you are unable to save the content.
```